# QuickFIX/J Multiple Logon

Tags: java, quickfix

Currently, the example provided in QuickFIX/J, only allow single executor to talk with single banzai.

From the settings in configuration file :
SenderCompID
TargetCompID

Their behavior is as follow :

Executor - I only allowed single connection from someone called Banzai
Banzai - My name is Banzai, and I will only connect to Exectuor

I would like to change the behavior of them to as follow :

Executor - I allow connection from anyone.
Banzai - My name is , and I will only connect to Exectuor

May I know how I can achieve that?

I try the following :
http://www.quickfixj.org/confluence/display/qfj/Implementing+Custom+Logons (Is this the correct way to have dynamically generated session?)

with only changing the code at Banzai side, and leave configuration file untouched, the connection wouldn't be allowed.

Is there other things else I need to change?

(1) Executor's code

(2) Configuration file for executor and banzai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quickfixengine uses the (BeginString,SenderCompID,TargetCompID) to distinguish sessions.

When server gets message, the engine gets those 3 values and finds associated session. The session then gets the message.

That means that you have to configure your SenderCompID (id if your server) and SenderCompID (id of the other side to which you wish to communicate).

You can setup multiple session in quickfixengine configuration so you can have multiple connections between server and client or multiple clients connecting to the same server.

However in all cases both client and server need to know the ID of the other side.

Comment: Ya. It works. It took me quite sometime to setup tough through experiment. Not much documentation on this.

Comment: Hi Cheok, can you please post an example, because I cannot get the Executor to send ExecutionReport to any session other than the originating order senders.